# Database Query (MySQL with PHP) not showing up in DOM

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to Query a many to many relationship, using a Junction Table, in MySQL to show which "workspaces" has which number of "members" subscribed to it.

The Query itself **works**, tried and tested in PHPMyAdmin and it returned the expected results. However. Upon using this query in the actual PHP code and executing it, **nothing** within the loop for reconstructing the results ready for the DOM **is showing**!
I even placed a little echo to see if the server is even executing that loop. It appears not. As if the query retrieved zero results, even though a var_dump just before the loop shows there is actually data being received from the server.

I am no novice with this procedure, I have completed it successfully multiple times, and yet this one really doesn't like me.

### Why will this not show up?

#### The Configuration Code

```
try {

    // Create PDO connection
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . "; dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PW);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    // Show Error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
    exit;
};
?>
```

#### The PHP code:

```
        <?php
            // Show and list threads
            try {
                // Prepare and gather Threads from DB
                $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT work.*, sub.*, mem.username, mem.avatar FROM TEAM_workspaces AS work LEFT JOIN TEAM_subscriptions_JCN AS sub ON work.workspaceID = sub.workspacesID LEFT JOIN TEAM_members AS mem ON sub.memberID = mem.memberID WHERE mem.memberID = :memberID');
                $stmt->execute(array(':memberID' => $_SESSION['memberID']));

                // This Block is Debugging Code to see what is happening
                echo '<br><br>';
                var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
                echo '<br><br>';
                $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                var_dump($row);

                // Cycle Database Records for Subscribed Workspaces
                while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo 'Hello, is this even being Parsed??'; // Added to see if the Loop is being executed at all
                    echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"><a href="workspace-single.php?workspaceID=' . $row['workspaceID'] . '">';
                    echo '<div class="col-md-10"><h2>' . $row['title'] . '</h2></div>';
                    echo '</a></div></div>';
                }
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo '<p class="bg-danger">' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
            }
            ?>
```

#### The Screenshot of the rendered stuff:

[image: Screenshot of Rendered PHP]

#### The Results from the Database (Easier to read)

[image: Easier to Read MySQL Query Completed within PHPMyAdmin]

### The Original (Working) Version of the Procedural Code

As a base to start off from, I had copied the code from another similar project. I have pasted this below to provide more of a picture of the situation.

#### The (WORKING) PHP Code from another Project

```
                <?php
                // Show and list threads
                try {
                    // Prepare and gather Threads from DB
                    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT threadID, title, description, author, date, imagepath FROM FORUM_threads');
                    $stmt->execute();
                    // $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

                    if( isset($row['imagepath']) ) {
                        $imagepath = $row['imagepath'];
                    } else {
                        $imagepath = 'default.bmp';
                    }

                    // Cycle Database Records
                    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"><a href="thread.php?threadID=' . $row['threadID'] . '">';
                        echo '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-sx-4 pull-left"><img class="thread-image" src="uploads/' . $imagepath . '" alt="Avatar for the thread ' . $row['title'] . '" /></div>';
                        echo '<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-sx-12"><h2>' . $row['title'] . '</h2></div></a>';
                        echo '<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-sx-12">' . $row['date'] . '</div>';
                        echo '<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-sx-12">' . $row['description'] . '</div>';
                        echo '<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-sx-12"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-md" href="compose.php?type=message&threadID=' . $row['threadID'] . '">New Message</a></div>';
                        echo '</div></div>';
                    }
                } catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo '<p class="bg-danger">' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: try removing all of `echo '<br><br>';
var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
echo '<br><br>';
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($row);`

Comment: Is $db your connection object or is it auto loaded  from within a frame work?

Comment: If you fetch all rows... then there are nothing to fetch.

Comment: if you need to work with the same recordset again assign the result of `fetchall()` to an array ~ ie: `$rows=$stmt->fetchAll()` and iterate through that recordset/array as I don't know if you can rewind the recordset cursor as you can in mysql.

Comment: @LarryLane No framework, but I've Updated the question to include the Connection Object of $db

Comment: @RamRaider I believe you are referring to the debugging code I put in after the problem arose? I've made it more clear now in the code. However, I am curious, are you saying that after a fetch to the PDO document, that it deletes the results? || we have to resend the query?

Comment: Have you tried it without the prepared statement yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` consumes your entire result set.

A subsequent `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` operation tries to fetch another row from the already-consumed result set, and so fetches nothing (just as if the result set were empty).

Comment: Looks like my own debugging code let me down. I had changed the fetchAll to the now fetch of the loop, however I had changed this WHILE the debugging script was in place, causing it to do exactly what you and and @RamRaider were trying to tell me. Many Thanks!